# How to best implement custom search on a Membership provider

Tags: asp.net-membership

Out of the box, System.Web.Security.Membership implements a couple of search methods:

- FindUsersByEmail
- FindUsersByName

I'm using the [WSAT project from CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/AspNetWSAT) to administer my Membership database. The tool implements extra profile properties in a ProfileCommon class.

Let's say I have a property called **Firm** in the user's profile.

I need to implement a custom search method to search on the Firm property, and I would like to do this all in code. Don't wanna write a stored procedure (since all the profile properties are stored in 1 database column in the WSAT tool).

Something like this obviously isn't the right way to do it, but here it is to just demonstrate accessing the user's profile properties:

```
    private MembershipUserCollection SearchByFirm(string firmName, MembershipUserCollection allRegisteredUsers)
{
    MembershipUserCollection searchResults = new MembershipUserCollection();

    foreach (MembershipUser user in allRegisteredUsers)
    {
        ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
        if (profile.Firm.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(firmName.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            searchResults.Add(user);
        }
    }
    return searchResults;
}
```

Can I turn this into some LINQ goodness?

Comment: Realizing that MembershipUserCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<T> either, which complicates things a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some help from a colleague who's good with linq. The challenge here is that MembershipUserCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable< T > (!).

```
        List<MembershipUser> searchResults = allUsers.Where(user => 
        Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName).Firm.ToLowerInvariant()
        .Contains(firmName.ToLowerInvariant())).ToList();
```

in this case allUsers is a List which I had to populate with the items in the Membership.GetAllUsers() collection.

Answer (score 22):

Well can't you just cast it?

```
IEnumerable<MembershipUser> searchResults = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();
```

Hope this helps you guys

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I created this extension method which I think it kinda works:

```
namespace WebDibaelsaMVC.Utils.MembershipUserCollectionExtensions
{
    public static class MembershipUserCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<MembershipUser> Where(this MembershipUserCollection userCollection,Func<MembershipUser,bool> func)
        {
            foreach (MembershipUser membershipUser in userCollection)
            {
                 if (func(membershipUser))
                    yield return membershipUser;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It also converts the `MembershipUserCollection` to an `IEnumerable<MembershipUser>` so all other LINQ methods work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function provided by microsoft. Here is the example of search membership user with UserName and Email Address

**Example:**
**Just Copy below function and implement it - Done...**

```
Public List<MembershipUser> SearchMembershipUser(string strUserName, String strEmail)
        {           
            IEnumerable<MembershipUser> MUser;
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserName) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmail)))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmail))
                {
                    MUser = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
                        .Where(x => x.UserName != CurrentUser && x.UserName == strUserName && x.Email == strEmail);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUserName))
                {
                    MUser = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
                        .Where(x => x.UserName != CurrentUser && x.UserName == strUserName);
                }
                else
                {
                    MUser = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
                        .Where(x => x.UserName != CurrentUser && x.Email == strEmail);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MUser = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(x => x.UserName != CurrentUser);
            }
            return MUser.OrderBy(x => x.UserName).ToList();
        }
```